# vba - open multiple websites

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

Please kindly assist regarding below issues.

**Background:**

I enter 25 stock codes in column B.
I would like to open them all in internet explorer automatically.

**Issue:**

After I run the below code, it only open 1 internet explorer window. And the url is "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="

How am i able to open multiple internet explorer windows/tabs and navigate to the stock codes which i want. Instead of just 1 internet explorer windows pop out?

**My computer info:**

1.window 8.1

2.excel 2013

3.ie 11

**My excel reference:**

Microsoft Object Library: yes

Microsoft Internet Controls: yes

Microsoft Form 2.0 Object library: yes

Microsoft Script Control 1.0: yes

**URL:**

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ibm

**Below is my VBA code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ie As Object




Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


For r = 2 To 50


With ie
  .Visible = 1
  .navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Cells(r, "B").Value

End With



Next r
End Sub
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After the `navigate` command you need to allow the `ie` object time to get the web page.

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
For r = 2 To 50
    With ie
        .Visible = 1
        .navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Cells(r, "B").Value
        Do While (.Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4): DoEvents: Loop   'READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

        ' do something with the page here

    End With
Next r
ie.quit: set ie = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating multiple IE Objects?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As Object
    For r = 2 To 50

        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With ie
             .Visible = 1
             .navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Cells(r, "B").Value
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```